# My asp.net core app doesn't find favicon.ico when it's deployed to IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I run my app in visual studio 2017 using IIS Express it is able to locate the favicon.ico in the wwwroot folder.
When it's deployed to IIS on a server then it can't find it.

I think it has to do with the url...

in development the url is https://localhost:44359
The favicon show up and if I manually type https://localhost:44359/favicon.ico then it returns it.

in production the url is https://localhost/reporting
The favicon doesn't show up and seems to be looking for it at https://localhost/favicon.ico (which returns a 404).
If I change that to http://localhost/reporting/favicon.ico then it returns the icon.

Can someone please suggest why it's not automatically looking for the icon under /reporting/  ??

I have a couple of routing issues as well, but other than that the app seems to work fine. I think the routing issues may have the same cause as the favicon.

Comment: you sure the file is actually getting included in your publish output and landing on the server?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes the favicon.ico is definitely in the wwwroot folder on the server

Comment: Please do not use the link tag. The right way to access the static files is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859345/setting-asp-net-core-2-0-favicon/53458847#53458847

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Browsers only check `example.com/favicon.ico` - they don't check in subfolders.

If you're putting it somewhere non-standard (you are!), you'll need to point browsers to it. In the `<head>` of your pages:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/reporting/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You say non-standard...but the favicon is where it was when visual studio created the project for me. Not sure if I did something wrong somewhere to cause it to be somewhere non-standard? I deployed following this guide: https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Comment: I tried copying favicon.ico from wwwroot to the parent folder "reporting" and it still doesn't find it

Comment: The standard location for a favicon is at the root of the domain name. Visual Studio assumes you're deploying the project to a domain name, so deploying to a subfolder requires some adjustments.

Comment: If you've moved your favicon to `example.com/favicon.ico` and it shows up there when accessed directly, try clearing caches or an incognito window. I've noticed Chrome not retry the default location after a 404 for a while.

Comment: Ah, so because I have it in Sites/Default Web Site/Reporting/ it's not finding it! :-/

Comment: Right...I put it another folder higher and it's now finding it.

Comment: I added "<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />" to the head section of my layout page and it's now showing the icon in production without me having to move it out of the wwwroot! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is an issue with finding static resources for applications that are in subfolders of a website.  However, in Razor pages, in the `<head>` you can use:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href='@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")'>
```

where the ~ refers to your application's wwwroot folder.

Comment: Also had the problem where it wasn't a path issue like @ceejayoz mentioned and this solved it! Should indeed be the accepted anwser!