# Setting ASP.NET Core 2.0 favicon

Tags: html, asp.net-core, favicon

I'm trying to add and set favicon.ico.

When I saw a initial project that Visual Studio 2017 make automatically, the `favicon.ico` file is just in the `wwwroot` directory and there is no setting for it.

So, I add favicon file into `wwwroot` directory.
But the favicon does not show up in any browsers.

How can I set the favicon in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Comment: There is a chance, that it is cache. If you open site without a favicon, browser remembers that there is no favicon. Try to open in another browser. The current one will update the cache in several days.

Comment: thanks for the idea @lilo.jacob - shift f5 did the trick!

Comment: @lilo.jacob Using Chrome, even in incognito mode it didn't show the new icon. Changing to Edge it appeared.  I thought incognito mode would start without any cache, but it seems like it remains some "memory" from normal window.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

wwwroot/index.html file has the link to favicon.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

is the code to add favicon to the website.

For .net core Single Page Application (SPA) project the favicon will be rendered from its own respective static file. For example if are using angular as client application there is `index.html` file inside `src` and in `index.html` you can link your favicon with following code

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Similarly, to set favicon in MVC project, you need to edit layout template which is normally inside `View > Shared > _Layout.cshtml`. You need to add `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` inside `<head></head>` tag. If you are using multiple layout then you need to edit other files as well.

Comment: hi, what if it's a web-api ? how would you set the favicon for an asp.net core web-api for example?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I have updated my answer please try it once.

Answer (score 11):

If your favicon.ico file is in wwwroot folder and if you are still getting 404 error when browser try to get favicon.ico, make sure you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your Startup.cs -> `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)`.

Please read
[Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for detail.

If you add favicon.ico in wwwroot and not in any subfolder, you don't need to add the `<link ...` tag in your html or cshtml.

Comment: For me, adding favicon.ico to wwwroot folder and pressing CTRL + F5 on my browser cleared the cache and made the new icon show up.

Answer (score 10):

In _Layout.cshtml include,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//.../content/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a headsup for anyone struggling with this issue.  If you're serving up a spa from .net core 2 (angular, react, other) sometimes the spa will look under the spa's static file's folder.  I struggled with for awhile and found that the only way i could get the favicon to show up with my angular app was to put the favicon and site.webmanifest in my app/assets folder.  Worked without any modification after that.  There are some suggestions out there to modify the content response types but didn't have to do that as long as the files were in the right folder.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently trying to do similar in a **.Net 7 Angular** project and also was getting **404's** despite trying everything above.

What worked for me was to put the file in the **asset folder under Client App**, and  to specify in index.html

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
```

Similiarly in nav-menu.component.html I had a logo in nav-brand that I also put in assets and referenced as below.

```
<img src="../assets/logo.png" height="48" />
```

Server side, I had Identity scaffolded, and placed my images under wwwroot/Indentity/images.  And then I referenced them as below in _Layout.cshtml.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Identity/images/favicon.ico" />

<img src="/Identity/images/logo.png" height="48" />
```

I do feel one should be capable of making it work with files in wwwroot, but it seems this work around is a fall back.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for .NET Core 6, I found I had to make sure all of this was correct:

1. favicon.ico is 16x16 and stored in the root of the wwwroot folder of the app, with CopyToOutputDirectory=Never

```
<Content Update="wwwroot\favicon.ico">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

2. A link in the `<head></head>` tag of the Layout or page

```
<link rel="bookmark icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

3. UseStaticFiles is called BEFORE any middleware

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.ApplicationServices?.GetService<IMyMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```